# How to check if enum type parameter with multiple values has a particular enum type

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, compare

I have a method returning enum.

```
-(EnumType)supportedEnum {
return EnumTypeA | EnumTypeB | EnumTypeC;
}
```

In another method, I am comparing if supported enum contains a particular enum type as below:

```
if ([Instance supportedEnum] == EnumTypeA) {
NSLog("Class contains EnumTypeA");
}
```

But it is not working as this condition is somehow false.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to define and use an `enum` as an *option set*. To do this you must first define your `enum` literals to have values which are powers of 2 which means, as the underlying hardware uses binary, that each value has exactly one bit set in it's value. You can also set the underlying type of the `enum` to one of: `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`; allowing your `enum` to have up to 8, 16, 32 or 64 literals respectively. For example:

```
typedef enum : uint8_t
{
   EnumTypeA = 0x1,
   EnumTypeB = 0x2,
   EnumTypeC = 0x4,
   EnumTypeD = 0x8,
   EnumTypeE = 0x10
} EnumType;
```

*Note: hexadecimal constants were used as they more clearly show only one bit is set in each value, but you and use decimal (or octal) if you prefer.*

*Note: Objective-C also provides a macro `NS_OPTIONS` that can be used to help define option set `enum`s, using it is a matter of choice. If you intend to inter-operate with Swift using it might be recommended. Look in Apple's documentation for it use.*

You combine your literals to produce a set value using bitwise-or, `|`, as you did in your method:

```
- (EnumType)supportedEnum
{
   return EnumTypeA | EnumTypeB | EnumTypeC;
}
```

which returns a value of `EnumType` with exactly 3 bits set.

To test for a particular value being present you use bitwise-and, `&`, e.g.:

```
if ([instance supportedEnum] & EnumTypeA)
{
   NSLog("Class contains EnumTypeA");
}
```

This works as `if` tests for its predicate expression being not equal to zero (this in an (Objective-)C peculiarity in that `if` does not take a boolean valued predicate but an integral valued one).

If you wish to test if any one or more of a set of `enum` literals is present you combine bitwise and and or. E.g. to test for `EnumTypeA` and/or `EnumTypeC` you would write:

```
if ([instance supportedEnum] & (EnumTypeA | EnumTypeC) ) ...
```

To test for all of a set of literals being present you must add an equality comparison. E.g.:

```
if ( ([instance supportedEnum] & (EnumTypeA | EnumTypeC)) == (EnumTypeA | EnumTypeC) ) ...
```

tests for both of `EnumTypeA` and `EnumTypeC`.

Using the bitwise and, or, xor and inverse operators, their compound assignment versions, and (in)equality operators you can set or clear individual literals in an `enum` value; union etc. two or more values; and test for any combination of literals being present/set and/or absent/clear.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It clarified my doubts about enums and bitwise operators use in ObjC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check reachability enum code
Here is the sample of enum it is just for your reference. don't use reachability code it is just for enum sample.

First you need to create variable with your enum "EnumType"
then you need to check your variable with "EnumTypeA", "EnumTypeB", "EnumTypeC"

```
- (void)updateInterfaceWithReachability:(Reachability *)reachability {
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL connectionRequired = [reachability connectionRequired];

    switch (netStatus) {
        case NotReachable: {
            connectionRequired = NO;
            self.isReachable = false;
        }
            break;

        case ReachableViaWWAN: {
            self.isReachable = true;
        }
            break;

        case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            self.isReachable = true;
        }
            break;

        default: {
            self.isReachable = false;
        }
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"\nisReachable = %d\n",isReachable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason your condition is always failing is because what you are doing in `supportedEnum` method is an Binary OR (|) operator.

so `supportedEnum` method returns 3 (0|1|2 = 3 and 1|2|3 = 3 ) 
you are checking that with EnumTypeA, thats why your condtion alwasy fails.

you can do with switch case or if-else as @vivek method. but but to clarify how to properly implement what you implemented. you can convert your enum to NSNumber and perform contains check.

Note: doing if-else or switch in case of a large number of enums will make your code bit long.

Eg:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    EnumTypeA,
    EnumTypeB,
    EnumTypeC,
    EnumTypeD
} EnumType;


//Here I am just converting the enum to Array of NSNumber.
-(NSArray*)supportedEnums {
   return @[@(EnumTypeA), @(EnumTypeB), @(EnumTypeC)];
 }


//Check by performing a contains check in the array.
if ([[self supportedEnums] containsObject:@(EnumTypeA)]) {
    NSLog(@"Class contains EnumTypeA");
}else {
    NSLog(@"Error in condition");
}
```